# What is the temperature variation between the lunar day and night on the moon?

Tags: the-moon, temperature

What is the approximate temperature and what factors cause this variation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Temperatures on the Moon](http://www.space.com/18175-moon-temperature.html) vary between extremes of 120 °C during the lunar day and -150 °C during the lunar night. Some craters near the poles have areas that are in permanent shadow, these can reach temperatures down to -247 °C.
The moon does not have a permanent "dark side". The moon rotates on its axis once every 28 days, so every part of the moon has a day-and-night pattern. The American expression "the dark side of the Moon" refers to the *far* side of the moon, which we never see from Earth.
The temperature range is so different from Earth due to these factors:

- the Moon has no atmosphere. Earth's atmosphere reflects some of the Sun's energy during the day and traps the heat during the night.
- the slow rotation results in very long days and nights, i.e. a long period of uninterrupted heating followed by a long period of uninterrupted cooling.
- The moon consists mostly of rock with a low heat capacity, which will heat up and cool down quickly. Earth's oceans have a high heat capacity, so they take much longer to heat up.

As on Earth, the surface temperature changes with the [latitude](http://www.lunarpedia.org/index.php?title=Lunar_Temperature).

The temperature below the Moon's surface [quickly stabilizes](http://www.asi.org/adb/m/03/05/average-temperatures.html). According to this link, only a meter below the surface, the temperature is a constant -35 °C. Note that this contradicts the previous link, which says that the subsurface temperature also changes with the latitude.

Comment: Do you mind articulating on the dark side.

Comment: Wow that link also says that, "The Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter measured temperatures of minus 396 F (minus 238 C) in craters at the southern pole and minus 413 F (minus 247 C) in a crater at the northern pole."

Comment: It might be useful to make more explicit that the temperature difference is due to energy from sunshine (presumably non-light solar emissions also add some energy, so 'sunlight' might not be 100% accurate) and lack of heat trapping and distribution (no atmosphere/oceans).

Comment: A [rudimentary calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law#Effective_temperature_of_the_Earth) of the black-body temperature of Earth comes out around 0°C. How does the surface of the moon get so hot?