# How many Lunar Surface Hasselblad cameras were left on the Moon?

Tags: apollo-program, camera

There were six Apollo missions that landed on the Moon. Each mission was equipped with at least two Lunar Surface Hasselblad cameras left on the lunar surface before ascent. But the total number of Hasselblad cameras should be greater than 12, these list of [photographic equipment](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap16fj/02photoequip.html) used for Apollo 16 counts 3 cameras left on the Moon. The third camera was equipped with a 500 mm lens, the first two with a 60 mm lens.

How many Apollo missions used a Lunar Surface Hasselblad Camera equipped with a
500mm Lens?

Answer (score 3):

The Apollo missions 11, 12, 14, 15, 16 and 17 were equiped with Lunar Surface Hasselblad Data Camera for each of the astronauts during their Moon walk. These cameras were equipped with a 60 mm lens.

The missions 14, 15, 16 and 17 used a third camera equipped with a 500 mm lens. See this [Apollo Image Libraries](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/picture.html). Magazines used with the 500 mm lens are listed as such.

So we have 12 cameras with a 60 mm lens and four additional cameras with a 500 mm lens. That are together 16 Lunar Surface Hasselblad Cameras that were left on the Moon before ascent to save weight. Only the film magazines with the precious photos were returned in the LM and then stored in the CM.

I found no information about the 500 mm lens used for the missions 11, 12 and 13.