# Chang'e- 4 safeguards to biological Contamination on the moon?

Tags: the-moon, lander, forward-contamination

What kinds of safeguards does Chang'e 4, China's lander on the dark side of the moon use, in order to prevent biological contamination on the moon?

How well are they documented?

Comment: It's about as safe as the bags of excrement NASA left on the moon.

Comment: A related but different question: [Is it ethical for Chang'e-4 to bring an entire ecosystem to the moon?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33500/12102)

Comment: The conditions on the Moon are the safeguard against anything biological from Earth reproducing itself outside a lander. Vacuum, temperature, lack of water, intensive UV radiation would kill any living unprotected cells. Moon is a perfect sterilization device. If a cell is not killed during hours there are a lot more days, weeks and months to do the remaining work.

Comment: @JCRM hold up, hold up... We left bags of poo on the moon? How had I never thought about that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Uwe answered my question

> The conditions on the Moon are the safeguard against anything biological from Earth reproducing itself outside a lander. Vacuum, temperature, lack of water, intensive UV radiation would kill any living unprotected cells. Moon is a perfect sterilization device. If a cell is not killed during hours there are a lot more days, weeks and months to do the remaining work.